# Will a browser still lazy load a script if it is already in the browser cache?

Tags: javascript, html, caching, lazy-loading

I'm using [lazyload.js](https://github.com/rgrove/lazyload/) to lazy load several scripts. Now I was thinking of just using a site-wide include which tells lazyload.js to load *all* scripts used on my site. Then I could let the browser decide if any of these scripts is already in the cache or not (and to load them if necessary).

That saves me from having to do testing in js whether something is already loaded (and I'm willing to accept the overhead of a couple of extra requests being made). **Would it work that way, or am I overlooking something?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not basing this on hard figures, but I think it safe to say that about 75~80% of the browsers being used today do a pretty good job caching the scripts. AFAIK, there are ways to force browsers *not* to use the cached scripts, but seeing as that's not what you want, that doesn't matter.

Yes, most of the browsers will, in fact, refer to the cahced scripts, and not request the files over and over again. Of course, [some people are concerned about their privacy](http://coding2learn.org/blog/2013/06/08/its-our-own-fault-dot-dot-dot-deal-with-it/), and will only browse the web in anonymous/incognito-mode (aka porn mode).
This causes the browser *to clear the cache when the browser window is closed*.
Why would you care? Well, I for one, find this very useful when developing my JS scripts.
hard-refreshing is something like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>. We've all grown the habbit of pressing those two keys 4~5 times, just to make sure. I've noticed that my co-workers do the same thing with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, too...

Comment: Are you sure that the majority of browsers will check the cache before lazy loading a script? Because I've also received an answer from someone who says everything will always be loaded regardless of the cache, and I don't really know what to believe now.

Comment: @Samuel: I've looked at the source of lazyload.js. All it really does, is create a new DOM element (script tag, check line 230 on github), and adds it to the DOM tree. The resulting behaviour is the same as when the tag was there to begin with: the browser will check if it has the script in cache for that domain, if so, it won't request the file again, but load the cached version. If not, it'll request the file. I've had a quick look at the other answers, but I don't quite know which one you're referring to when you say you had an answer saying it will always perform the request.

Comment: I meant Dmitry's answer (at the bottom). But your answer explains exactly what I was unsure about. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

How about cache-control?

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
```

Maybe this will be the right thing for you.
Look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_meta_httpequiv.asp) for more information.

Comment: Ok, but why "no-cache"? Because I would like the browser to refer to the cached version when possible. Shouldn't it be "public" or "private"? And isn't "public" the default already?

Comment: Yeah public is the default. But you know the browser automatically takes the cached version.

Comment: Why the w3fools link?

Answer (score 2):

Lazy loading is not always about bandwidth preservation, it also has a lot to do with CPU/battery preservation.  If you lazy load something, whether in browser cache or not, you are loading it as and when required and thus not wastefully executing code that is never used.  If you load everything up front, there is a fixed cost on CPU and battery for every visit to a page, whether 80% of the modules are used or not.

To spare the battery life of mobile devices, you are better off adopting the proper lazy loading approach.  But for desktops, you are better off preloading everything, since the preloading cost is relatively small.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen it work the way you have explained and I've seen it not work. However, there are also seldom occurrence of a double load, which will make overhead even greater.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't understand your last sentence. What do you mean by it exactly?

Comment: Seriously, if you want the bounty, just give me at least a halfway decent answer. I'm not giving you the bounty if your answer stays like this.

Comment: I dont care about the bounty. Second, when I say it will double load, the cached version will load on top of the lazyload. It wont affect the javascript working, but sometimes it can slow it down based on how long it is.

Comment: Sorry if my response was a little too harsh, it's just that sometimes when I set a bounty, and don't have any answers yet, people try to get the bounty by giving a very simple answer and don't reply or explain it. But what you're saying is that it might even slow things down.. That sucks.

Answer (score 1):

In short: **It depends**

The browser is most likely to not request for the script if it is present in the cache unless explicitly specified.

However, it is completely upto the browser's discretion to request the script or not..

Comment: Your question recieved my attention :) @Samuel

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. So I guess it is not as simple of a question as I thought it would be. Basically the answer is; it depends.

Answer (score 0):

No, it would not work.

If you tell lazyload to load scripts then it loads scripts.
Lazyload has no access to browser cache and could not determine if some resource is in cache or not.
Also, script loading order is important, so browser can not use javascript file if previous javascript files are not loaded. Browser could determine does javascript files depend on each other or not.

In case you are considering to create just "load all" via lazyload:
it is better to create just one JavaScript file and load it in the end of your pages.

Comment: lazyload doesn't have access to the cache, true enough, but lazyloadjs doesn't actually _load_ your scripts. It creates a new DOM node, which, and appends it to the current DOM tree. JS has nothing to do with the DOM, so once the src attribute is set, it's up to the browser how the script is requested. Most modern browsers _will_ refer to the cache first.

Comment: You are right, browser will check if the requested resource (js file) is in the cache or not. But then browser will load resource that is not in cache from the server. And you can't tell browser: "load file if file is in the cache". You just tell: "load file". And browser load from cache or from server.

`lazyload.js` do the same: it just load js files.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said in my answer, too... The way the file/resource is loaded is up to the browser, and most browsers will cache the scripts... obviously, if they're not in cache they will be requested as per HTTP request... but your answer states that it'll request _all scripts, every time_. At least, thats how the OP understood your answer

Comment: `lazyload.js` just load js file. Immediately then code occurs. If you want just place "load all my js" lazyload on the page, then it is better to just concat all js to a single file and load it in the end of the page. The reasons are:
1. Lesser number of HTTP request.
2. No need of `lazyload.js` library

Comment: Sorry, I am just 3rd day here. When press enter it submits comment.

3. placed in the end of the page it will to block loading of other resources 

4. Single js file is simpler to maintain (if it is hard to navigate you always may use concat before deploy)

Comment: lazyload.js _does not load anything_. It adds a script tag to the DOM, sets the `href` attribute and applies a callback `onreadystatechange`. That's it. You can include CSS files, JS files... anything really. creating a single JS/CSS file isn't always possible in today's world. Claiming a single js file is easier to maintain is just BS. If you're the only person working on it, then it may be easier _for you_. When working with 10 devs on a project, a single file is a pain (and the best way to ensure merge-conflicts)_

Comment: There's nothing you're saying that _I don't already know_. I know how js files are requested, I know what lazyload.js does (I've checked the github source prior to answering). Your answer is just _wrong_. If you don't fix it, I'll have to -1 it